# PyMongo - ConnectionFailure

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, nginx

I want to connect to my mongoDB using pymongo. But I have this error :

```
raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I have obviously checked url,password...etc of the database connection.
My mongoDb instance is running.

```
sudo service mongodb status
mongodb start/running, process 10199
```

Thanks!

(Log)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 173, in <module>
    run_app(opts.config)
  File "app.py", line 159, in run_app
    Application(config).start(config)
  File "app.py", line 75, in __init__
    conn = pymongo.Connection(config.dbhost)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 236, in __init__
    max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 369, in __init__
```

Comment: What does your connection look like in your code and where are you using it? Need some more details that just the log and the error.

Comment: What are you using for `config.dbhost` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MongoClient` constructor.

Assuming default port on loopback, where your database is `my_db` and your collection is `my_coll`, try:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
my_connection = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = my_connection['my_db']
coll = db['my_coll']
#Sample cursor
my_cur = coll.find()
```